# Is it okay to connect directly power supply to usb 5v? +<->+ & - <->- to maintain power?

Tags: 5v, pc

I am working on an extention cable for my PC usb hub. It goes about 5m using UTP 5e cable, it sometimes can read the data from usb, sometimes it can't. I figured, it is because of voltage drop. So I am intending to make external power supply for the hub to maintain the 5 V voltage.

Is that okay?
I am afraid about the difference voltage reference 5V ground (-) and (+) between PC and power supply. Can this mess up my PC?

Comment: The problems are more likely down to CAT5e cable not being the correct specification for USB data. How is it wired?

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend USB with cat5e cable. It is not rated for the required current for USB 5V power, and it has 100 ohms characteristic impedance while USB requires 90 ohms. It is also not OK to parallel your 5V source from PC with a 5V power supply, most likely you end up frying your PC. Buy a 5m USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

*"Is it ok?"* 
Well, this is not the best or more reliable solution, because Cat5e is not the correct cable for USB data, but you can try - of course you will not be using this in a "mission critical" environment, and maybe you just want to tinker.

Google for "add external power for USB" and you'll find many pages with instructions to do something like that.

*"Can this mess up my PC?"*

Make sure that you **don't connect +5V from PC/USB port to +5v from external power supply**, and make sure that **your power supply really feeds only 5v** (beware of cheap power supplies: some of them output a brief higher-than-5v pulse in the moment when they're powered on).

[image]
If you are still afraid of damaging your PC, you could put an intermediate hub just after the PC. So, if your "powered hub" (HUB2 below) misbehave, you will mess only HUB1:

```
                +5v -------X                                              Power source
                Data+  ------------------------------------------------   HUB2
PC  ----  HUB1  Data-  ------------------------------------------------    (as image
                GND ---------------------------------------------------    above)
```

In worst case, it will not work and you will lose your time - but your PC will be safe.