# Hard wiring micro USB port to 5v power jack internally on a tablet

Tags: usb

I have a tablet with a DC power jack that requires 5 volts, which I do not have the connector for. Currently I am charging it with 2 wires soldered to the internal side of the jack on the PCB. To avoid buying a charger, I am wondering if I can just solder 2 wires internally from a nearby micro USB port to the power jack. This way, I can just plug in  micro USB cable to charge it.

Would there be any problems when doing this? (Obviously it can depend on hardware but in general) The answers from [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501250/is-it-okay-to-connect-directly-power-supply-to-usb-5v-to-maintai) state that you shouldn't connect external 5v power sources to USB ports, but that would mean that plugging in any USB cable connected to power will break that port, which seems really easy to do. Plus I do it all the time and nothing happens.

Assuming the voltage can always reliably be 5v, it seems to me that I could just connect them together, right?

Comment: You can't connect pins of internal USB port that is not intended for charging to the charging input. Buy the charger. Or change the DC input jack to another USB connector.